# Using R to drop rows that meet a certain condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Been noodling on this a while and can't quite seem to get it to work.

Let's say I had the following data

| Year | Office | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A27 | ABC |
| 1 | A27 | ABC |
| 1 | B22 | XYZ |
| 1 | A27 | ABC |
| 1 | B23 | XYZ |
| 1 | B23 | XYZ |
| 2 | A28 | ABC |
| 2 | B42 | XYZ |
| 2 | B42 | XYZ |
| 2 | A28 | ABC |
| 2 | A28 | ABC |
| 3 | B42 | XYZ |
| 3 | L17 | ABC |
| 3 | L17 | ABC |
| 3 | L18 | ABC |
| 3 | B42 | XYZ |

(as a csv)

```
Year,Office,Location
1,A27,ABC
1,A27,ABC
1,B22,XYZ
1,A27,ABC
1,B23,XYZ
1,B23,XYZ
2,A28,ABC
2,B42,XYZ
2,B42,XYZ
2,A28,ABC
2,A28,ABC
3,B42,XYZ
3,L17,ABC
3,L17,ABC
3,L18,ABC
3,B42,XYZ
```

This is just representative, the actual data file is over 100k lines.  What I need to do is drop any records (whole rows) where:

- In the same year
- A single location
- Has more than one office

So in the above example, in year 1 I would drop all records associated with location XYZ since it has two different offices (B22 on line 3 and B23 on line 5).  Year 2 is all okay.  In year 3 I would drop all records associated with location ABC because it has two locations, L17 and L18.

I'd like to do this using dplyr functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is not clear, however, if I understood correctly, is this what you need?

```r
# Libraries ----
library(dplyr)

# SOLUTION -----
df %>%
  group_by(Year, Location) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Office) == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>